# Confusion about positive class and sklearn metric pos_label=0

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, roc, confusion-matrix, auc

I have a binary classification problem for detecting AO/Non-AO images, using PyTorch for this purpose.
First, I load the data using the ImageFolder utility.
The Dataset class to label mapping in `dataset.class_to_idx` is `{0: 'AO', 1: 'Non-AO'}`.
**So, my 'positive class' AO, is assigned a label 0, and my 'negative class' Non-AO is assigned a label 1.**
Then I train and validate the model without any issues.
When I come to testing, I need to calculate some metrics on the test data.
Here is where I am confused.

**[Method A]**

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_score)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

[image: method a]

**[Method B]**

```
# because 0 is my actual 'positive' class for this problem
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=0)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

[image: method b]

Now, this second curve is basically the mirror of the first one along the diagonal, right?
And I think, that it can't be the correct curve, because I checked the accuracy of the model by directly comparing `y_true` and `y_pred` to get the following accuracies.

[image: accuracy]

Apart from this, here is what my confusion matrix looks like.
[image: confusion matrix]

1. So, my first question is, am I doing something wrong? What is the significance of the curve from Method B? Can I say that Method A gives me the correct **ROC curve** for my classification task? If not, then how do I proceed for getting the correct curve?
2. What does `true positive` or `true negative` or any of the other terms signify for my **confusion matrix**? Does the matrix consider 0 : AO as negative and 1 : Non-AO as positive (I think so, yes) or the vice versa?
3. If 0 is indeed being considered as negative, when I actually want 0 to be considered as positive, how can I make changes to reflect so in the matrix (because I am using the matrix later to calculate other matrics like specificity, sensitivity, etc) ?